# Qt SMTP SSL failed to connect

Tags: qt, email, ssl, smtp

I have developed an app to send email using this SMTP client:

[text](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/tree/v2.0)

It works perfect BUT! Only on PC where I develope the app. If I try to use it anywhere else I always have a failed to connect error, and I never even go to a login step.

```
smtp.connectToHost();
    if (!smtp.waitForReadyConnected())   {
        writeLog("Connection Failed");
        return;
    }
    smtp.login(m_login, m_password);
    if (!smtp.waitForAuthenticated())    {
        writeLog("Authentification Failed");
        return;
    }
    smtp.sendMail(message);
    if (!smtp.waitForMailSent())    {
        writeLog("Mail sending failed");
        return;
    } else {
        writeLog("The email was succesfully sent.");
    }
    smtp.quit();
```

Can anybody explain do I need to configure something on my target PC for my app works correctly with this SSL method? Everything seems easy and I have not an idea what can be wrong

I use a app password for my email. I tried to use mail.ru and gmail.com accounts and always had the same result - works on my PC, doesnt work on else

Answer (score 1):

The main thing was about a library as I supposed, but just putting libraries in the app folder didn't help.

My solution's steps:

- Find out which version of SSL uses your Qt with:

  ```
   qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl() 
            << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() 
            << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
  ```
- Download and install OpenSSL version you need.
- Put `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` from `.../OpenSSL/bin/` to a bin folder of your compiler (MSVS, MINGW).
- Rebuild your project and put `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` in the app folder too.

Answer (score -1):

MimeMessage message;

```
EmailAddress sender("xxx@host.com", "Your Name");
message.setSender(sender);

EmailAddress to("xxx@host.com", "Recipient's Name");
message.addRecipient(to);

message.setSubject("SmtpClient send message");

MimeText text;

text.setText("Hi,\nThis is a simple email message.\n");

message.addPart(&text);

SmtpClient smtp("smtp.gmail.com", try using this port also can you share the Debbuger logs (Port 587, Port 2525, Port 5870) , SmtpClient::SslConnection);

smtp.connectToHost();
if (!smtp.waitForReadyConnected()) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to connect to host!";
    return -1;
}

smtp.login("your_email_address@host.com", "your_password");
if (!smtp.waitForAuthenticated()) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to login!";
    return -2;
}

smtp.sendMail(message);
if (!smtp.waitForMailSent()) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to send mail!";
    return -3;
}

smtp.quit();
```

Comment: u posted a code from repository, of course I used this, read my message again. Btw I found a solving. Thanx for attention.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).